# How to convert string to int in C from a file without using library function?

Tags: c

I am trying to open an file that has many lines of numbers in it, then convert it from a string into an integer.

I would like to do this without using any library functions, so no atoi, no strtol nor strtoul.

This is what my code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* required for atoi. */
int main(void) {
  int  i, len;
  int result=0;
  double numbers;
  char num[20];  /* declares a char array. */

FILE *file;  /* declare a file pointer. */
file = fopen("test22.txt", "r");  /* opens the text file for reading only, not writing. */

while(fgets(num, 100, file)!=NULL) {       /* this while loop makes it so that it will continue looping until the value is null, which is the very end. */
    len=strlen(num);
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        result = result*10 + ( num[i] - '0' );
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);
    }
fclose(file); /* closes the file */
return 0;
}
```

Right now it's returning numbers that are not present in the text file.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h> /* required for atoi. */` <-- And why would you try to reinvent the wheel? Also: would `ctype.h` be out of the question, too, or are you happy to use `isdigit`?

Answer (score 0):

You're not resetting `result` to zero with each new line, so it just keeps accumulating.  Change

```
while(fgets(num, 100, file)!=NULL) { 
    len=strlen(num);
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        result = result*10 + ( num[i] - '0' );
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);
    }
```

to

```
while(fgets(num, 100, file)!=NULL) {
    result = 0;
    len=strlen(num);
    // account for newline - should really be smarter than this.
    // I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader... ;)
    for(i=0; i< (len - 1); i++) {
        result = result*10 + ( num[i] - '0' );
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the answer. It's still printing numbers that are not in the text file.

Comment: @N.Vaz What is the contents of the text file?  The code as posted doesn't check at all what the input data is, so if there are characters in the file that aren't numbers or newline characters, it will output the wrong values.  Also, if the numbers are too large to fit into an `int`, you'll have problems.

Comment: It's just numbers that have been randomly generated and stored into it. See: http://puu.sh/rEhMO/4fa9e11f35.png

Comment: @N.Vaz The code as posted doesn't account for the `-` characters.

Comment: What would I need to add for it to account the negative numbers? I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The function `fgets` retains the `newline` at the end of the string (if present), which you are trying to convert as a digit. I suggest a loop like this:

```
for(i=0; i<len && isdigit(num[i]); i++)
```

and you must also have

```
result = 0;
for(i=0; i<len && isdigit(num[i]); i++)
```

before each loop.

Note that you cannot just reduce the result of `strlen` because the last line of the file may not have a `newline` at its end.

Edit: since you posted a file with negative numbers, here is an example that will convert them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int getnum(char *str) 
{
    int result  = 0;
    int neg = 0;
    if(*str == '-') {
        neg = 1;
        str++;
    }
    while(isdigit(*str)) {
        result = result * 10 + *str - '0';
        str++;
    }
    if(neg) {
        return -result;
    }
    return result;

}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", getnum("123456789\n"));
    printf("%d\n", getnum("-987654321\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
123456789
-987654321
```

Comment: Hi Weather Vane, thank you for the response. I edited the code and it's actually giving me then numbers that are in the text file. However they are not in order and it returns 0s, which I imagine is because of negative numbers. See: http://puu.sh/rEiqM/24311788c2.jpg

Comment: Note: corner case: `getnum()` may or may not work with the string version of `INT_MIN`.  Likely not a concern of OP.

Comment: @chux yes, range issues in general but I kept it simple.